# How do you add tabs to a Microsoft Teams Bot?

Tags: microsoft-teams

While there is a lot of documentation on how to add a tab to a Team, I can't seem to find any docs on how to create and drive the user to tab content like the ones demonstrated in T-Bot.

**Can someone point me to any docs on how to add tabs to a bot?**

This is what I am talking about:
[image: Picture of bot tabs in Microsoft Teams]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This capability is not yet available for developers.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Create a static tab in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-static) documentation section to know more about personal tabs.