# Is T-Bot "Help" section made with Teams Wiki?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I cannot find a way to create a wiki like the one I see in the T-Bot Help section 
[T-Bot Help Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfu2S.png)

I tried Teams Wiki but it does not display in the same way.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi411.png)

Same for OneNote.

Any idea what kind of controller is used to create the Help section in T-Bot ?

Comment: Or is it code oriented like in the T-Bot Tabs question ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619012/how-do-you-add-tabs-to-a-microsoft-teams-bot

Answer (score 0):

T-Bot's help section is not a Microsoft Teams Wiki tab. It's a personal scope [static tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-static).

You can create similar page structure easily using CSS styles. Please check [How TO - Vertical Tabs](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_vertical_tabs.asp).

Comment: It is not indeed. Which is why I was wondering how-to. T-Bot is an App, is it not ? And some tabs are bots, others are connectors (wiki like for the Help tab). But I was not aware for the static tab and I thank you for that. I will check but my feeling now is that there is a way to load pages (Word online or GitHub Page) and to parse them to obtain that kind of display and I will definitely check that. (cannot give +1, not enough reputation, but I will).

Comment: Ok, a bot is a specialized app, first tab of T-Bot is the real bot. Other tabs are decorations. Yet the Help tab can be a unique tab in a simple App.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/design/framework/apps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/design/framework/bots